# Remove duplicates from array

Tags: php

I have two arrays, like this:

```
$array1 = array(
'ADAIR',
'ADAM',
'ADAMINA',
'ADDISON',
'ADDY',
'ADELLE',
'ADEN',
'ADOLPH',
'ADRIANNA'
);

$array2 = array(
'ADAIR',
'ADAMINA',
'ADRIANNA'
);
```

How do I make a third array, without duplicates? **We should take first array and remove from it duplicates from second array.**

Comment: This question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want ADAIR, ADAMINA and ADRIANNA to be in the third array or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Array-diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$array3=array_diff($array1,$array2);
```

Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comment: +1 I think this is what the OP meant, though he could clarify a bit

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Combine both arrays into 1, then run them through the array-unique function

```
$result = array_unique($combined);
```

Comment: @RiaD I think the question is a bit ambiguous; it asks "How do I make a third array, without duplicates?". Well, this answer is perfectly valid then.

Comment: @RiaD Yeah, I'm still confused by what he actually wants then. . .  The bold part was added later, I answered the question as it was asked originally, I think. . .

Answer (score 0):

@grunk deleted a perferctly valid answer, so credits not to me:

```
$unique = array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2));
```

[codepad.org/NVkuml5g](http://codepad.org/NVkuml5g)

Comment: You'll get a merged version of $array1 and $array2, which doesn't seem to be what the OP wanted.